# Mutable MultiMap to immutable Map

Tags: scala, dictionary, set, immutability, multimap

I create a `MultiMap`

```
val ms =
  new collection.mutable.HashMap[String, collection.mutable.Set[String]]()
  with collection.mutable.MultiMap[String, String]
```

which, after it has been populated with entries, must be passed to a function that expects a `Map[String, Set[String]]`. Passing `ms` directly doesn't work, and trying to convert it into a immutable map via `toMap`

```
ms.toMap[String, Set[String]]
```

yields

```
Cannot prove that (String, scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]) <:< (String, Set[String]).
```

Can this be solved without manually iterating over `ms` and inserting all entries into a new immutable map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the problem is mutable set. So turning into immutable sets works:

```
scala> (ms map { x=> (x._1,x._2.toSet) }).toMap[String, Set[String]]
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Set[String]] = Map()
```

Or even better by following Daniel Sobral suggestion:

```
scala> (ms mapValues { _.toSet }).toMap[String, Set[String]]
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Set[String]] = Map()
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe it was because it's needlessly verbose when you can just write `ms.mapValues(_.toSet)`

Comment: I don't really care who down voted, only why. In my opinion the verbosity is not the point of the question nor the answer so it shouldn't be a reason for down voting.

Comment: It's a bit of a pity that you have to iterate over the map, but it looks as if that's the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `mapValues` to change the `Set` alone?