# Scala :- Gatling :- Concatenation of two Maps stores last value only and ignores all other values

Tags: scala, performance-testing, scalaz, gatling

I have a two Maps and I want to concatenate them.

I tried almost all example given here [Best way to merge two maps and sum the values of same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key) but it ignores all values for key `metrics` and only stores last value.

I have downloaded `scalaz-full_2.9.1-6.0.3.jar` and imported it `import scalaz._` but it won't works for me.
How can I concate this two maps with multiple values to same keys ?

**Edit :-**

Now I tried

```
  val map = new HashMap[String, Set[String]] with MultiMap[String, String]
  map.addBinding("""report_type""" , """performance""")
  map.addBinding("""start_date""" ,start_date)
  map.addBinding("""end_date""" , end_date)
  map.addBinding("metrics" , "plays")
  map.addBinding("metrics", "displays")
  map.addBinding("metrics" , "video_starts")
  map.addBinding("metrics" , "playthrough_25")
  map.addBinding("metrics", "playthrough_50")
  map.addBinding("metrics", "playthrough_75")
  map.addBinding("metrics", "playthrough_100")

  val map1 = new HashMap[String, Set[String]] with MultiMap[String, String]
  map1.addBinding("""dimensions""" , """asset""")
  map1.addBinding("""limit""" , """50""")
```

And tried to conver this mutable maps to immutable type using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386918/mutable-multimap-to-immutable-map) as

```
val asset_query_string = map ++ map1
val asset_query_string_map =(asset_query_string map { x=> (x._1,x._2.toSet) }).toMap[String, Set[String]]
```

But still I get

```
i_ui\config\config.scala:51: Cannot prove that (String, scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]) <:< (St
ring, scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]).
11:10:13.080 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ - val asset_query_string_map =(asset_query_string map { x=> (x
._1,x._2.toSet) }).toMap[String, Set[String]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create two MultiMaps but when I tried to concatenate `val final_map = map1 ++ map2`
and I tried answer given here [Mutable MultiMap to immutable Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386918/mutable-multimap-to-immutable-map)

But my problem was not solved, I got

```
config\config.scala:51: Cannot prove that (String, scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]) <:< (St
ring, scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]).
```

finally it solved by

```
val final_map = map1 ++ map2
val asset_query_string_map = final_map.map(kv => (kv._1,kv._2.toSet)).toMap
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not related with a concatenation but with a declaration of the metrics map. It's not possible to have multiple values for a single key in a Map. Perhaps you should look at this collection:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap

Answer (score 1):

**You can't have duplicate keys in a Map.**

for simple map it is impossible to have duplicates keys,if you have the duplicates keys in the map it takes the last one

but you can use MultiMap

```
import collection.mutable.{ HashMap, MultiMap, Set }
val mm = new HashMap[String, Set[String]] with MultiMap[String, String]
mm.addBinding("metrics","plays")
mm.addBinding("metrics","displays")
mm.addBinding("metrics","players")
println(mm,"multimap")//(Map(metrics -> Set(players, plays, displays)),multimap)
```